# VBA - leave current cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that reacts to a double click. This action works just fine, my question though.. after filling in the form that pops up due to the double click action the form is unloaded, no problem here, but the user is left in edit mode inside the cell he double clicked on.

Now normally in Excel you can press CTRL-Enter and the cell will just simply be selected and you out of edit mode. How do I achieve this in VBA ?

All I can seem to work is moving the cell up one, but really just want the user to exit Edit mode and stay on the current cell, the one he double clicked on.

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Cells(ActiveCell.Column, ActiveCell.Row - 1).Activate
Cells(ActiveCell.Column, ActiveCell.Row).Activate
Unload Term
End Sub
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to see what that shows up? I have answered so many EXCEL-VBA questions quickly like that than I can possibly try to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `BeforeDoubleClick`'s `Cancel` argument, which ... cancels clicking into the cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```